# HP MSL2024 LTO6 2 Drive & HP ProLiant DL180 G6

Tags: backup, hp, backupexec

Wanted to get some insight on setting up the below.
I have an existing backup server:
HP ProLiant DL180 G6 running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-Bit & Backup Exec 12.5.
And recently purchased a HP MSL2024 2 Drive LTO6 Library. It comes with SAS. So I purchased, a HBA H222 card for the DL180 server, but noticed on the MSL2024 there's 4 SAS points of connection, as it's a 2 drive library, the supplier I purchased the equipment from suggested that only 1 to 1 SAS key cable was required.

But whne I went throught the manual of the MSL2024 it showed a 4 to 1 SAS key cable for the library.

I plugged it all in and fired up the library and backup server, and backup exec only sees the new library as a single tape drive not a robotic library.

So would I be requiring the 4 to 1 SAS key cable as the manual shows, but it doesn't state that it's required.

Has anyone else had any experience or exposure setting this up?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the HP StorageWorks drivers?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need one SAS SFF-8088 cable per drive... Plug into port A. Port B is for cascading. E.g. In and Out.

[image]

Comment: Correct. Either: Port 1 of the SAS HBA should be plugged into the first LTO Drive's "IN"; and first drive's "OUT" port should be connected to the "IN" of the second drive; all with typical SFF-8088 cables. **OR** Get a SFF-8088(4x) to 4x SFF-8088(1x) fan out cable (will have 4 "downstream" connections for up to 4 drives.